# how to know if a path exists in firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure is the following:

```
-posts
         -postID
              -name
               -text
```

I am retrieving posts by

```
Database.database().refrence.child(“posts”).observe(.childAdded){ (snap) in
  If snap.value is nsnull{}else{
    The retriving data code here
  }
}
```

When clicking. On posts

```
Database.database().refrence.child(“posts”).child(postID).observe(.childAdded){ (snap) in
  If snap.value is nsnull{}else{
    The retriving data code here
  }
}
```

And everything is going good except, How to Know if a certain post with a certain postid gets deleted, since it won’t go through  in code in the observe function.
I want to show a message showing that the post is deleted by looking if the path exists or not.

Note: i don’t want change the value of the keys if a post is deleted .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know when any post gets deleted, listen for the `.childRemoved` event similar to your current `.childAdded`.

If you want to know if a specific post (so once you know its ID) exists, you can do so by observing its `.value` event. E.g.

```
ref.child("rooms/room1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        print("true rooms exist")
    }else{
        print("false room doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey,thanks for answer,i think i didn’t been extremely clear,i need to check if a path exists also for other stuff,also if i used observesingleevent(of: .value) it also wont go in the function if the path doesn’t exist in firebase,imagine if i was observing for a post with observing single event it still wont go in the function if postId is removed from firebase

Comment: I have search throuch firebase documentation but they did say anything

Comment: The `.value` event will fire even if there's no value.

Comment: @Abdull I think you may misunderstand. This answer is two separate things; 1) If you want to watch for posts to be added, use .childAdded on the posts node. If you want to watch for posts to be removed, use the .childRemoved on the posts node. Both of those will pass the added or removed node via a snapshot to the closure so you can process it 2) The second part of the answer is a general way to see if a path exists and unrelated to the first part. If the question is *How to Know if a certain post with a certain postid gets deleted* the answer is use .childRemoved so do NOT use 2) for that

Comment: Yes,thanks observe single event by vaue does return if snapchot exists,thank you